# sed/regex: How to match a '<' or '>' in a string

Tags: regex, sed

I'm looking to match all less than ('<') or greater than ('>') signs in a file using sed. I only want to match the single character

My goal is to replace them with `' <'` and `'> '` (ensure they have white space around them so I can parse them easier) respectively.

For example, it would match:
(without space within the tags)

```
< p >Hey this is a paragraph.< /p >< p >And here is another.< /p >
```

.. and turn it into (note the spaces)

```
 < p > Hey this is a paragraph. < /p >  < p > And here is another. < /p >
```

Here's what my initial (wrong) guess was:

```
sed 's/<{1}|>{1}/ <> /' ...
```

It matches the whole word/line, which is not desired, and it also does not replace correctly.

Anyways, any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You _really_ don't want to parse HTML with regular expressions. Use an HTML parser. (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/ which is one of the most-upvoted answers on SO for good reason)

Comment: @Wooble: while I generally agree to your assertion, using regexes can still be okay for testing and the like ... if it exceeds this, use a proper parser, though.

Comment: Haha yeah, I know. I've seen that one. I'm writing a toy academic HTML formatter in perl for a very small subset of tags. I am just using sed and regex to ensure it has the whitespace that my perl code needs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try two substitutions to make it easier:

```
sed 's/</ </g ; s/>/> /g' file
```

Comment: or you can do this - `sed -e 's/</ &/g' -e 's/>/& /g' file`